# Enable Cloud SQL for GAE Legacy Project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to enable and create a Google Cloud SQL instance per: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/before_you_begin#enroll

However, the "Cloud SQL" menu item does not appear when I open my project in Google Cloud Console as referenced in step #3.

I noticed that if I navigate to Cloud Development -> Push-to-deploy I get the error message: "Push-to-deploy is not available for this project because it is a legacy project."

How can I get Cloud SQL working with my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud SQL Instances are not restricted to work only with AppEngine apps in the same project. You can just create a new project at https://cloud.google.com/console (which will have Cloud SQL enabled), and from that project create a new Cloud SQL Database. Just make sure you replace the default authorized AppEngine project with the old one on the Create screen.